# Is it possible in git to have a branch-like sequence of commits that gets applied on top of another branch?

Tags: git, quilt

I have been using git for a long time and think am quite familiar with it, but I recently encountered an use case that is bothering me:

There is a *main* software development team that develops the `main` branch. This is a regular git branch and they develop using usual git practices.

Then there is a *customer_A* support team that develops customizations for customer A. This customizations involve modifying the code in `main`. What the  *customer_A* team currently does is they develop their customizations in branch `customer_A` that they periodically *rebase* to `main`. The problem with this approach is that every time that they *rebase* they need to *force-push*, with the usual *force-push* drawbacks.

What I am wondering is if there is a way for team *customer_A* to develop in some "branch-like" fashion so their "branch-like" sequence of commits gets applied on top of `main` without needing to *force-push* their "branch-like" sequence of commits every time they want to *rebase* to the latest `main` branch.

Before you ask, the customizations for each customer involve modifying different pieces of code for different customers, and they are unpredictable until we talk to the customer. If they were always the same, this would be a typical use case: We would simply externalize the configurations into some configuration files developed in a different repo with each customer team developing their own configuration independent of `main` or other customer teams.

Comment: "on top of" implies rebasing, which implies force-pushing. Have you considered simply merging the main branch into the customer_A branch?

Comment: If you don't want to force-push to old branch, create a new branch.

Comment: Can't you just periodically merge the latest version of the `main` branch into `customer_A` branch? This will give a non-linear history, though. If you require a linear history, it is technically impossible to do this without rebasing the `customer_A` branch (ie. you need to re-write history, and inevitably get those "usual drawbacks").

Comment: Thank you. We've been testing the suggestion of _merge `main` into `customer_A`_. We have found that for us the non-linear history, while not ideal, is less of a problem than _force push_  and rewriting-history, so we are switching to merge.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, for several months we tried the `git merge` approach. It was better than the git rebase and force push but the non-linear history is ugly and we were not completely happy.

Eventually we switched to using `quilt` to maintain a list of *patches* involving possible customizations as well as a *series* file for each customer listing which patches/customizations each customer gets. We use git to version control our patches and series files. We are very pleased with this approach and it addresses all our needs without any drawbacks. Unlike the git based approaches, the quilt approach feels completely natural for our workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting a bit with a "more careful" way of doing merges to working/development branches while maintaining history in a reasonable way.  The basic idea is that you **never** want to merge *from* main, only *to* main, so your main history always ends up "clean".  The way you do this when bringing some other branch up to date is:

- first create a new temp merging branch on main
- merge your working branch (customer_A in this case) to the temp branch
- fast-forward the working branch (customer_A) to the head of the temp branch
- delete the temp branch

That's it.  Once you do that, your working branch can still later be merged to main without screwing up the history, and the history on the working branch is reasonably clean (it is the main-line history with work-in-progress merged into it).

The fast-forward should work unless someone else has committed to the development branch while you're doing this (in which case you'll need to back out and redo this with their change included)